# incompatible type GridLayout cannot be converted to layout manager

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, grid-layout

Here is the my demo code, please check out why this code given me problem.

```
package gridlayout;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridLayout {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(()->{

        MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
        //frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(0);
        //frame.setTitle("Grid Layout");
       // frame.setDefault
    });
  }
}

class MyFrame extends JFrame{

public MyFrame(){

    setTitle("My Programm");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    add(new MyPanel());
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
    }
 }

class MyPanel extends JPanel{
  private JButton display;
  private  double result;
  private String lastCommand;
  private boolean start;
  private JPanel panel;

// private static final int n = 4; 
  public MyPanel(){


    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     //setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));

    result = 0;
    lastCommand = "=";
    start = false;
    display = new JButton("0");

    setEnabled(false);
    add(display, BorderLayout.NORTH);

//        panel = new JPanel();
//        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout());

         GridLayout expLayout = new GridLayout(0,4);
}

public void addButtons(String Name){
    JButton button = new JButton(Name);
   }
}
```

Comment: which arguments are you passing to GridLayout constructor ?

Comment: Also show your imports. There should not be an issue here since the "true" GridLayout implements LayoutManager interface

Comment: providing argument int @Ansharja

Comment: sorry  forget to add import java.awt.GridLayout;
but after this i facing "reference to GridLayout is ambiguous" @AlexeyR.

Comment: @sandyRoy seems that you're importing the correct GridLayout and Incorrect one at the same time. Find import of GridLayout that is different from import java.awt.GridLayout and remove it

Comment: @AlexeyR. i change my import  files to javax.swing.*, java awt.* now i facing this error "constructor gridlayout in class gridlayout cannot beapplied to given types:
required : no arguments
foun: int,int
reason actualand fromal args lists differ in length"

Comment: @AlexeyR. if i remove the args i again saying "incompatible type";

Comment: Just copy and paste your code here to your question (not re-type it manually). Becouse we can only guess what's wrong with it having no the complete picture.

Comment: class MyPanel extends JPanel{
    private JButton display;
    private  double result;
    private String lastCommand;
    private boolean start;
    private JPanel panel;

   // private static final int n = 4; 
    public MyPanel(){
    
  
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
         //setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));

        result = 0;
        lastCommand = "=";
        start = false;
        display = new JButton("0");

        setEnabled(false);
        add(display, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout());

Comment: last comments has my codes but how could you understand this.

Comment: @sandyRoy I meant edit your question with your code. Do not post it in comments. Do not forget about imports. Paste the entire code of your .java file..

Comment: @AlexeyR. Demo Code Updated

Comment: @sandyRoy okay, I see. Check my answer and comment there if any further detail required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be in that you have this code:

```
 public class GridLayout {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
       public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        EventQueue.invokeLater(()->{

            MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
            //frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(0);
            //frame.setTitle("Grid Layout");
           // frame.setDefault
        });


      }

    }
```

Since you have defined your custom class in the package where other classes reside and that class is called `GridLayout`, those two names conflict when you do `panel.setLayout(new GridLayout())` 
To avoid it either rename your custom `GridLayout` so that it has some different name or try `panel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout())` instead of `panel.setLayout(new GridLayout())`

P.S. - As @XtremeBaumer correctly noticed you should avoid using the well-known class names either from JDK distribution package or from other well-known libraries (at least you should understand the risks if you still required your classes to have such the names)

Comment: you should also suggest to try and never use already existing class names like `Integer` `String` and so on, because this mostly only causes confusion

Comment: oh thanks, you noticed the correct problem, coz i write another code with differ cls name that's work fine. good dude. God Bless you.@Alexey R. You are right, @XtremeBaurner this name confliction waste my whole day.
Thank to all bros.